# How to provide config values for lambda functions using golang

Tags: go, aws-lambda, config, serverless

How to provide config files along with the lambda function written in golang. I created a folder named config inside the project root and provided the config.But unfortunately that doesn't worked after the project got build.And I know this is because of we are building it as a binary file.So, What was the best way or approach to provide config files along with the lambda function for golang?

```
var config map[string]string
var filename string

//Checks the stage and loads the Configuration file
if len(event.Stage) > 0 {
    filename = "configs/config.json"
}

configFile, err := os.Open(filename)
defer configFile.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Printf(err.Error())
    return config, err
}
jsonParser := json.NewDecoder(configFile)
err = jsonParser.Decode(&config)
return config, err
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the config files to the zip containing the Go binary

For example, assuming you have a Handler.go with a configs directory containing configs.json then

```
go build -o Handler Handler.go && chmod +x Handler && zip -r handler.zip Handler configs
```

should make a zip containing the configs directory and the Handler binary which can be uploaded to Lambda

There are alternatives to using files such as AWS Parameter Store that you may wish to consider